# Why is there a constructor of the class std::basic_string with a parameter of the type std::string_view absent in the C++ Standard

Tags: c++, string, constructor, c++17, string-view

What is the reason that the standard class `std::basic_string` does not have an "implicit" constructor that accepts as its argument an object of the type `std::string_view`?

I would expect that this program will compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

struct A
{
    void f( const char *s ) const
    {
        std::cout << "A::f( " << s << " )\n";
    }        
};

struct B
{
    void f( const std::string &s ) const
    {
        std::cout << "B::f( " << s << " )\n";
    }        
};

template <typename... Bases>
struct C : Bases...
{
    using Bases::f...;
};

int main()
{
    C<A, B>().f( std::string_view( "Hello" ) );
    // or
    std::string_view s( "Hello" );
    C<A,B>().f( s );
}
```

Comment: @G.M. Sadly your link just shows all the contructors. Are you referring to the template constructors at the bottom? (10 and 11). They might accept string_view, and indeed they do, but only if you understand "convertable_to" to cover "is".

Comment: Actually, string HAS a constructor from string view: [basic_string.h:650](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h). It has a brief: 'Construct string from a string_view'. So i don't think, this is duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because many of the `string_view` accepting functions are ambiguous with the `std::string` overload of the same function.  Take

```
std::string s({"abc", 1});
```

for example.  This is either create a `std::string` from a `std::string_view` by calling the `string_view` accepting constructor or create a `std::string` via

```
basic_string(const CharT* s, size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

[LWG 2758](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2758) brought this issue up originally and [LWG 2946](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2946) finished adjusting all of the `string_view` taking functions to templates.  By doing this none of the older string interface needed to be adjusted so older code wont break when compiled under C++17.

Comment: But you could write std::string s( { {"abc", 1 } } ); and there is no ambiguity.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Would that even work?  [It doesn't here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6c1deac8bcc5d6b)

Comment: This works.  #include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

struct A
{
    A( const char *, size_t  ) { std::cout << "A( const char *, size_t )\n"; }
    A( const std::string_view & ) { std::cout << "A( const std::string_view & )\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    A a( { { "abc", 1 } } );
}

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ah, nice.  That said, having to write `std::string s( { {"abc", 1 } } )` instead of `std::string s({"abc", 1});` makes the language harder for new comers.  It violates the principal of least surprise if `std::string s({"abc", 1});` just doesn't work.

Comment: The whole point of this hackery is to avoid breaking existing code. It doesn't matter if the existing code can be rewritten in some other way.